# Best way to handle large amount of inserts to Azure SQL database using TypeORM

Tags: sql-server, azure-functions, azure-sql-database, typeorm

I have an API created with Azure Functions (TypeScript). These functions receive arrays of JSON data, converts them to TypeORM entities and inserts them into Azure SQL database. I recently ran into an issue where the array had hundreads of items, and I got an error:

```
The incoming request has too many parameters. The server supports a maximum of 2100 parameters. Reduce the number of parameters and resend the request
```

I figured that saving all of the data at once using the entity manager causes the issue:

```
const connection = await createConnection();
connection.manager.save(ARRAY OF ENTITIES);
```

What would be the best scalable solution to handle this? I've got a couple ideas but I've no idea if they're any good, especially performance wise.

1. Begin transaction -> Start saving the entities individually inside `forEach` loop -> Commit
2. Split the array into smaller arrays -> Begin transaction -> Save the smaller arrays individually -> Commit
3. Something else?

Right now the array sizes are in tens or hundreads, but occasional arrays with 10k+ items are also a possibility.

Comment: Use a Table-Valued Parameter. Dunno how to do that from Azure Functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up doing this the easy way, as TypeORM already provided the ability to save in chunks. It might not be the most optimal way but at least I got away from the "too many parameters" error.

```
// Save all data in chunks of 100 entities
connection.manager.save(ARRAY OF ENTITIES, { chunk: 100 });
```

Answer (score 0):

One way you can massively scale is let DB deal with that problem. E.g. use External Tables. DB does the parsing. Let your code only orchestrates.

E.g.

1. Make data to be inserted available in ADLS (Datalake):

   - instead of calling your REST API with all data (in body or query params as array), caller would write the data to ADLS-location as csv/json/parquet/... file. OR
   - Caller remains unchanged. Your Azure Function writes data to some csv/json/parquet/... file in ADLS-location (instead of writing to DB).
2. Make DB read and load the data from ADLS.

   - [First `CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE tmpExtTable LOCATION = ADLS-location](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-external-table-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15&preserve-view=true&tabs=dedicated)
   - Then `INSERT INTO actualTable (SELECT * from tmpExtTable)`

See formats [supported by `EXTERNAL FILE FORMAT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-external-file-format-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15&tabs=delimited).

You need not delete and re-create external table each time. Whenever you run `SELECT` on it, DB will go parse the data in ADLS. But it's a choice.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, a very interesting approach! I will keep this in mind if massive scaling is required at some point.